# Modern Warfare 3 Multiplayer with Guest

Tags: xbox-network, call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3

I noticed that when playing MW3 on Xbox Live with a guest (someone that doesn't have a gold subscription and is just your "second"), they start at the same level as you with all of your same classes.

I also noticed, after playing for a while, our levels were different.  Can the guest account level up separately from the main?  What happens when you restart the Xbox, does the Guest get brought back to your level or are they forever on their own "path"?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What happens to the XP points of the second player in dual screen?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/34572/what-happens-to-the-xp-points-of-the-second-player-in-dual-screen)

Answer (score 3):

The guest levels up separately from the gold member but starts as the same level when you first sign in as the guest. Same as Black Ops. And it resets when the guest signs out.