# Does playing with a bad guest player damage my stats in MW3?

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3

If I have a friend join in for co-op muliplayer online splitscreen in Modern Warfare 3, and he does badly (as the second player, not the first) does his bad game effect MY stats?

Comment: I'm 99% sure that the answer is no, they don't, but I don't have enough data/experience to say for sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it does not. If he is not signed in as a separate profile, he will play as 'guest' (Xbox 360). His stats will be tracked for the duration of the session as his own and upon ending the session (Guest signed out), his stats will be lost and be reset to the primary account's stats. The primary account holder's stats will only be affected by his gameplay. If the second player is signed in as a separate profile, his stats will be tracked on that profile.

Comment: Is there any way to source this?

Comment: This [SE Question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/34572/what-happens-to-the-xp-points-of-the-second-player-in-dual-screen) references it, and in my experience (I used to play Split-screen a lot), my partner *never* had his stats added to mine. I can't find any authoritative sources confirming this, however.

Comment: @Ender I have over 200 hours across several consoles and never had guest stats added. I have 0 usage on the ACR and always have my guests use it. Still zero usage.

Comment: @Dustin - the ACR is a great weapon - you should try it out (with a silencer and kick)

Comment: @SSumner, I did use it on my old PSN account and you're definitely correct. I just found that, for me, it tended to lead to poor gameplay habits (relying less on tactics/positioning and more on weapon strength).

Comment: @Dustin - not to troll, but isn't that kind of the point of CoD? It's hardly a 'tactical' game, it's all about weapon strength and run and gunning. Don't get me wrong, I enjoyed it for awhile before I moved on, but it's not really that sort of game.

Comment: I mean that using the ACR made me develop habits that made me worse with other weapons (like shotguns). Because I don't particularly like it, I decided to not use it anymore to boost my kdr and focus on weapons I like. Not deprecating anyones play style, just trying to make myself better. Anyway, I found that when I use ACR-like weapons infrequently I tend to play better on the rare occasions I do use them.

Comment: Ahh, I see. I was always terrible with shotguns, so I didn't worry about that. I pretty much exclusively used Assault Rifles/SMGs, with occasional snipers.

Answer (score -1):

I think it does not I mean if the guy that you are playing with is in guest it shouldn't do anything